# Import multiple CSV fields into one MySQL field

Tags: python, mysql, csv

I have a table like this

```
mytable(`id` int, 'number1' varchar(11), 'number2' varchar(1200))
```

Also I have cvs-like file

```
111111111,222222222,333333333,44444444,,,
222222222,333333333,
111111111,555555555,666666666,
```

They are separated by ","(or something else)
The csv have 100 colunms.

I would like to combine the second column to 100rd loumn into mysql "number2",
the first column into mysql "number1".

like this:

```
id number1    number 2
1  111111111  222222222,333333333,44444444
2  222222222  333333333
3  111111111  555555555,666666666
```

So can I use LOAD DATA INFILE to load the file into the table? How can I do this..? or have other method?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option which creates a *new* column combining columns 2 through 100:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'input.csv'
INTO TABLE myTable
COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ','
IGNORE 1 LINES 
(id, number1, number2, ..., number99) 
SET newCol = CONCAT(NULLIF(number1, ''), NULLIF(number2, ''), ..., NULLIF(number99, ''));
```

Then, you can remove columns 2 through 100 from within MySQL:

```
ALTER TABLE myTable
DROP COLUMN number1,
DROP COLUMN number2,
...
DROP COLUMN number99
```

Comment: this method is too complex，must be build 99 columns.   but thanks.

Comment: I don't see why this method is conceptually difficult at all.  AFAIK there is no avoiding mentioning the columns when you aggregate and then delete.  It should take maybe 5 minutes of work to implement.

Comment: thank you very much .  I  have a problem. In the csv , some columns are null, "concat" how to avoid these columns.
Only columns with numeric values are merged.

Comment: @user3804623 Use `NULLIF` or `COALESCE` on each column which might have `NULL`, and replace that `NULL` with whatever value you want.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the function `file()` to open the cvs file ;

use the function `explode(',', $each_line)` to seperate each line with `,`,

I did not understand your demand clearly,I think simple code could like this:

```
$file_items = file('file.cvs');
foreach($file_items as $item) {
    $item_arr = explode(',', $item);
    // combine $item_arr[0]... $item_arr[99] ,you get $number1, $number2;
    $sql_insert = "INSERT INTO mytable (number1, number2) VALUES(number1, $number2)";
}
```